# Is there a good way to handle conversions between arrays and strongly typed collections automatically?

Tags: c#, collections

Background:

I have a big solution where hundreds of functions take strongly typed collections as inparameters and using them as return values.

The solution references a generated proxy wich converts calls to a webservice that always returns collection in the format int[] or Order[] or wathever type it is. The proxy wraps them up as IntCollection or OrderCollection.

Now I want to reference the assembly directly. When I do that I get the interface against the Arrays instead of the proxy generated strongly typed collections. This of course breaks all the code.

I am looking for a smart way to handle this and avoid rewriting thousands lines of code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `IntCollection` etc belong to you? You could add an implicit conversion operator:

```
class IntCollection : Collection<int> {
    public IntCollection() : base() { }
    public IntCollection(IList<int> data) : base(data) { }
    public static implicit operator int[](IntCollection items) {
        return items.ToArray(); // LINQ, but can do manually
    }
    public static implicit operator IntCollection (int[] items){
         return new IntCollection(items);
    }
}
```

Normally, this would be one of the times that interfaces (`IList<Foo>` etc) help - but interfaces don't often work very well in web services. Depending on what the code currently does, you might be able to do a "replace all" fix - a bit drastic, though; other than that... you're going to have to change odd bits of code.

a few thoughts:

- switching to `var` (in C# 3.0) might minimize the change - i.e. `var orders = svc.GetOrders()`; in most cases, the different implementations will have "similar enough" APIs

  - resharper might be able to help with this
- using LINQ (`.ToList()`, `.ToArray()`) might serve as a shim

Comment: @Marc - I've never seen the implicit operator before, would be useful in some of my code. If his collection is based on a generic list then he can use the non linq ToArray.

Comment: ToArray is available on generic collections without LINQ

Comment: @ck - Not all do, e.g. Dictionary.

Comment: @ck - it is available on `List<T>`, but not on `Collection<T>` etc.

Comment: @Stevo3000 - sure you have: int i = 5; decimal d = i;

Comment: @Marc - Very true, what I meant was that I'd never seen a way to tell my own objects to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Create the strongly typed collection from the array. For example you can create a generic list from an array.

```
int[] oIntArray;
List<int> = new List<int>(oIntArray);
```